# IntelliJ 16 Community: How to assign a keyboard key to show/hide the terminal

Tags: intellij-idea

In intellij there are keys to show hide tool windows (for example Cmd+1 shows or hides the project tool window).

However by default there is no key for the terminal. I wonder if I can assign a keyboard shortcut like Cmd+4 to show/hide the terminal.

I am using intellij on Mac.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Preferences -> Keymap` and search `Terminal`, double click and select `Add Keyboard Shortcut`

[image]
Then you can just enter your shortcut in the dialog